# Moving text from a textfield to textarea with a button

Tags: java, user-interface, textarea, textfield

This code compiles and runs but it does not copy the text from the text field then place it into the text area.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class NameGameFrame extends JFrame
{

    static JTextField textfield = new JTextField(20);
    static JTextArea  textarea = new JTextArea(30,30);

    public static void main( String[] args)
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Name Game");
        frame.setLocation(500,400);
        frame.setSize(800,800);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter the Name or Partial Name to search:");
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);

        panel.add(label,c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(textarea,c);

        JButton button = new JButton("Search");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 1;
        panel.add(button,c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panel.add(textfield,c);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
        static class Action implements ActionListener
        {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {

           //This is the code that should  perform the task
            String name  = textfield.getText();
            textarea.append(name);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Java programming and I apologize if my questions are simplistic.

Comment: Did you forget to add `Action` to your button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appen below code to your program after ther declaration of button 
ie. `JButton buuton  = new JButton("Search");`

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionAdapter()
{
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
     {
          textarea.setText(textfield.getText());
     }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked perfectly when I used ActionListener as the parameter as supposed to ActionAdapter. Thanks for the assistance.